# Scipy sparse.kron gives non-sparse matrix

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am getting unexpected non-sparse results when using the kron method of Scipy's sparse module. Specifically, matrix elements that are equal to zero after performing the kronecker product are being kept in the result, and I'd like to understand what I should do to ensure the output is still fully sparse.

Here's an example of what I mean, taking the kronecker product of two copies of the identity:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

s = sp.eye(2)

S = sp.kron(s,s)

S 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 8 stored elements (blocksize = 2x2) in Block Sparse Row format>

print(S)

(0, 0)  1.0
(0, 1)  0.0
(1, 0)  0.0
(1, 1)  1.0
(2, 2)  1.0
(2, 3)  0.0
(3, 2)  0.0
(3, 3)  1.0
```

The sparse matrix S should only contain the 4 (diagonal) non-zero entries, but here it also has other entries that are equal to zero. Any pointers on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting from sparse to dense to sparse again decreases density after constructing sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169282/converting-from-sparse-to-dense-to-sparse-again-decreases-density-after-construc)

Comment: Thanks a lot @hpaulj, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

In

[Converting from sparse to dense to sparse again decreases density after constructing sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169282/converting-from-sparse-to-dense-to-sparse-again-decreases-density-after-construc)

I point out that `sparse.kron` produces, by default a `BSR` format matrix.  That's what your display shows.  Those extra zeros are part of the dense blocks.

If you specify another format, `kron` will not produce  those zeros:

```
In [672]: sparse.kron(s,s,format='csr')                                         
Out[672]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [673]: _.A                                                                   
Out[673]: 
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```